# In Stripe Integration with PHP E-commerce site customers can pay without creating plan and subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am new to Stripe integration but I want to know if customers on my e-commerce site can pay using credit card without creating stripe plan or stripe subscription. See the code below what I mean:

I only want customer to pay once and no recurring payments and monthly subscriptions.

```
// create plan
    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array( 
                "product" => [ 
                    "name" => "Monthly Subcription" 
                ], 
                "amount" => $itemPrice, 
                "currency" => $currency, 
                "interval" => $planInterval, 
                "interval_count" => 1 
            )); 

    // create subcription 
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array( 
                    "customer" => $customer->id, 
                    "items" => array( 
                        array( 
                            "plan" => $plan->id, 
                        ), 
                    ), 
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can take payments without using Subscriptions. There are a few options for taking one time payments. The first option is their Checkout, which is a Stripe hosted payment solution and requires a minimal code. You can learn more about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout).

The second option is to build your custom payment flow. This quickstart [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) walks you through the Integration steps. You can select the language, PHP, on the Backend section to get what you're looking for.

Finally, there is the no code solution which is the Payment Links. You can learn more about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links).

The custom payment flow might be what you're looking for but wanted to share the other options as well.